# Why Facebook SDK gives result to acitivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I have initialized facebook sdk from fragment with context of fragment. When i am going to logged in with facebook it gives callback to activity's method of "onActivityResult" but basically i want it to fragment's method of "onActivityResult". This is just a question regarding Facebook SDK. I have solved this problem by managing current opened fragment. I didn't find any stuff regarding this thing. Please answer.
Procedure of initializing facebook SDK::

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
    loginButton = new LoginButton(getContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_about_me"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new RegisterFbLoginResCallBack(getActContext()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK calls onActivityResults so that you can pass the results data to the SDK. This way Facebook SDK understands how her activity ended (was there a login success, user cacellation etc).

From any fragment you can get the fragment's Activity by calling getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Android => all event handlers in Activity, and after this you are bypassing it to you fragment. It's not only about FB SDK fragment. It's about all fragments. And only if you setting some kind of OnClickListner in your fragment -> for this event listner you will receive answer in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about how to can pass that information over, it may not be as hard as you think. For example:

Activity ----> onActivityResult() { some logic }
Fragment ----> you want to do something with response from Activity

If you are using MVP, you can have your presenter interface some method doSomethingWithFBResponse() that receives whatever you need from your activity. At that point, just continue with the logic you intended to do as a callback in your presenter.